# Передать значение переменой через URL в другой скрипт

Tags: php

Пытался передать значение двух переменных через URL  в другой скрипт следующим образом, но ничего не получается

```
echo "<HTML> <HEAD> <META   CONTENT='0';  URL='localhost:8080/hatsker.ru/vpered.php?left=$left&right=$right';></HEAD></HTML>";
```

Подскажите как правильно можно передавать переменные через URL в интернете ничего толкового не нашёл

Comment: а что не работает? переменные `$left` и `$right` существуют? Вроде должно работать. можете еще так попробовать: `echo "text1".$left."text2";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что именно не получается? Передать значение переменных?

Смотрите:

```
 index.php:
 <?php
 $left = 100;
 $right = 100;
 echo '<a href="localhost:8080/hatsker.ru/vpered.php?left='.$left.'&right='.$right.'>';
 ?>
```

На странице на которую перешли:

```
 <?php
 $left = $_GET["left"];
 $right = $_GET["right"];
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пост

```
<?php
    if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8080/hatsker.ru/vpered.php');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, count($params));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
        curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
    }
?>
```

На странице приёма все параметры будут в переменной $_POST

И параметры будут не видны пользователю если оно того требуется конечно

Comment: Блин, только сейчас подумал, что курла возможно с локалкой работать не будет, я точно не могу сказать

Comment: В любом случае спасибо, я правда сделал как в ответе выше, но всё равно спасибо

Comment: @Novichok45 если не касается безопасности то  я бы использовал первый вариант!=) Если надо безопасней и скрыть от пользователя ссылку то мой с курлом